# Move folders to new folders using part of the original folder name with delimiter

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to move folders into new folders based on the last part of their name. The delimiter is an underscore. The number of underscores in the folder names vary wildly. I found code that uses the first part of the name but can't figure out how to make it use the last part of the name. In awk it would be something like awk -F'_' {Print $NF}.

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%G IN (*) DO (
    FOR /F "delims=_" %%H IN ("%%~G") DO (
        MD "%%~H" 2>nul
        MOVE "%%~G" "%%~H"
    )
)
```

Edited to add examples:

```
Folder_01 -> md (if necessary) and move into folder "01"
Folder_02 -> md (if necessary) and move into folder "02"
weird_folder_name_a2d -> md (if necessary) and move into folder "a2d"
```

Comment: Can you gives some examples on how the old folders are and how the new folders should look like ex: "This_Is_Old_Folder" -> "Is_Old_Folder" or "This_Is_Old_Folder" -> "Folder". Meaning only the part after the last underscore or all the parts after the first underscore?

Comment: Folder_01 -> 01
Folder_02 -> 02

Comment: That doesn't explain much as you only used an example with 1 underscore, yet on your question you talk of folders with several underscores "The number of underscores in the folder names vary wildly"

Comment: Correct. The number of underscores in the folder names vary wildly. I am looking for the string after the last underscore.

Comment: Ah ok now it''s clear. I didn't see that you edited your answer...

Comment: Ups, I mean I didn't see your updated "question" Please see updated answer....

Answer (score 1):

Would this be the expected result:

[image]

```
@echo off

if exist "%~1" (IF not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)
pushd "%~1"

FOR /D %%a IN (*) DO call :MoveTo "%%~a"
exit


:MoveTo
set "FolderName=%~1"
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ("%FolderName:_=\%") DO (
                                                 MD "%%~nxa" 2>nul
                                                 MOVE "%FolderName%" "%%~nxa"
                                                )
goto :EOF
```

Comment: This doesn't work if folders have lots of underscores or dashes. You end up with folder names cut in half. I appreciate the help though. I just solved it in WSL so I don't need a pure Windows solution anymore.

Comment: Ok, good to know you solved the problem

Comment: @Priora I would say based on your overly simplistic example in your question this solution should work. You should always provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of the code you are using and any supporting input for the script.

Comment: @Squashman I would say based on the question, which by the way is crystal clear, this solution does not work. Re-read these lines: "...move folders into new folders based on the last part of their name. The delimiter is an underscore. The number of underscores in the folder names vary wildly...In awk it would be something like awk -F'_' {Print $NF}."

Comment: @Priora the `FOR /F` code grabs the last section of the folder name.  It does this by first changing the name of the underscore to a a backslash to make the for command think it is a folder path. Using the FOR command modifiers `%%~nxa` then grabs the last section of the path.  I have not directly tested the code myself but have used this technique in the past.  You basically confirmed in your first comment under this question that the folder name examples in actual Question have multiple underscores and not just one.  And I said your input examples in your question should be representative.

Comment: @Priora I see where the miscommunication is.  I overlooked the fact that Ricardo had edited the code.  The initial code was incorrect but the revised code does indeed work. So I was confused by your initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to do it, using Linux or WSL:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec perl -e '$a="\Q@ARGV"; $a =~ /([^_]+$)/; `mkdir -p $1 && mv $a $1`' "{}" \;
```

Taken from: https://askubuntu.com/a/538270

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).